# Correlations between variables in a repeated measures experiment

Tags: regression, correlation, lme4-nlme, repeated-measures

I have a dataset with, to make things simple, 3 variables (*Response*, *PredictorA*, and *PredictorB*) measured in multiple subjects over time. I am administering a toxin to my subjects (lets say there are ~10) and measuring all three variables at 3 or 4 timepoints (separate days) after exposure.

There are several types of analysis I’m interested in. Firstly, does *Response* change significantly after exposure? For that I have been using lme4 in R, running mixed models with roughly the formula: `lmer(Response ~ Day.Post.Exposure + (1|Subject_ID))`. This I am pretty comfortable with, although I know things can get more nuanced.

What I’m also interested in is the degree to which *PredictorA* and *PredictorB* are associated with changes in *Response*. My initial sense was that I could run more mixed models (*Response* ~ *PredictorA* + (1|Subject_ID)) and (*Response* ~ *PredictorB* + (1|Subject_ID)). But I think this isn’t capturing everything.

Based on the biology of the experiment, my suspicion is that changes in *PredictorA* cause changes in *PredictorB*, and that *PredictorB* causes most of the change in *Response* (with other changes in *Response* being caused by *PredictorA* directly, as well as several other factors, not all of which I can measure).

I’m not directly manipulating either *PredictorA* or *PredictorB*, so I don’t think I can make any conclusions re: causation, but what would be the best way to investigate that potential? More mixed models, with both *Predictors* included? Should I also control for the effect of time? I don’t think time itself has an effect on *Response*, it’s just that over time other parts of disease worsen and those processes end up impacting *Response*.